# Why is the value zero going in my custom database table?

Tags: wp-query

I am working on a task where I have to insert a customer into database table in WordPress. It's a custom table so I used a template file and applied a `wp_query`. The rest of the data is getting into the table in the proper way, but the `book_ref` value is always `0`.

I have assigned the data type `varchar` for `book_ref`.  I made a string from two strings by using `substr` and saving it `$ref':

```
$ref=substr($from,0,2).substr($to,0,2);

$wpdb->insert( 'customer_info', array( 'post_id' => $q, 'name' => $a,'lname' => $b, 'email' => $c,'mobile' => $d, 'phone' => $e,'adress' => $g,'accom'=>$f,'v_name'=>$taxi1, 'remark' => $h,'from'=> $from.''.$flight,'to'=> $to,'t_date'=>$t_date,'pass_num'=>$adult,'vehicle_num'=>$texi_no,'total_price'=>$price,'book_ref'=>$ref,'status'=>$status  ), array( '%d', '%s','%s', '%s' ,'%d', '%s' ,'%s', '%s','%s' ,'%s', '%s','%s' ,'%s', '%s','%s','%d'  ) );

echo $wpdb->last_query;
```

it gives this output:

```
(`post_id`,`name`,`lname`,`email`,`mobile`,`phone`,`adress`,`accom`,`v_name`,`remark`,`from`,`to`,`t_date`,`pass_num`,`vehicle_num`,`total_price`,`book_ref`,`status`) VALUES 
(0,'Dinesh ','Kumar','dinesh@macadamia.co.in',1234567890,'1122','New Market empior','Chd, 22','Limousine','rerer','Trapezaki','Svoronata','11/22/2013-02:20','3','1',300,0,1)
```

where book_ref is always 0.

Any idea what I missing?

Answer (score 1):

A quick count shows me that you have 18 columns there, but only 16 types in the type array. Double check your types.